# Fastest way to remove or hide duplicate in list displayed with datatable

Tags: python, django, django-models, datatable

I have a list of objectA.

```
list = [ObjectA, ObjectA, ObjectA, ...]

class ObjectA(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    list = models.TextField()
    ...
```

The list is made by merging 2 query sets like that :

```
list = ObjectA.filter(Q(list__name='list1') | Q(list__name='list2')).distinct()
```

I display the object in the template by using dataTable.

I want to remove "duplicate" in the list OR hide them when I display the list with dataTable.

The object is considered as duplicate if

```
objectA1.title == objectA2.title && objectA1.description == objectA2.description
```

The others parameters can be different in the 2 duplicates.

The list contains 3'000 to 5'000 ObjectA. What is the fatest way to remove in my views.py or hide in my template.html the duplicate ?

Comment: I don't understand how you are defining ObjectA, are the `param1, param2` all class attributes? Would it be possible to just create a `set` of all the objects instead of a list? that would eliminate duplicates just because of the nature of a set.

Comment: I'm updating my question with more precisions on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to write `__init__()` method, otherwise you params will be shared between all instances of `ObjectA`

> ```
> def __init__(self, title, description):
>      self.title = title
>      self.description = description
> ```

2. Override comparison operator `__eq__`

> ```
> def __eq__(self, other):
>      return self.title == other.title && self.description == other.description
> ```

3. Just add list of objects to `set` and you will get collection of unique objects